# unable to read a .list extension file in c++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, file-handling, ext.list

i am stuck at a small problem... i have to read data from a .list file but for some reason im just able to do it... i've obviously checked the path many times and i tried copying the data in a text file and using it and it works fine but i really need to read from a .list file.. am i supposed to read differently as compared to a text file? if so how?

here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main (int args[])
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("D:\transaction.list",ios::in);
    if (!infile) {
        cerr << "Can't open input file " << "D:\\transaction.list" << endl;
        char ch;
    std::cin>>ch;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

and this shows cant open file...

here's the list file:

```
C12397,P342,P8,P563,P456 
C3452,P546,P8,P673,P675 
C1238,P1
C12397,P8,P673,P42
```

any idea on what im doing wrong? thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\t` is a special character in C/C++ you need to pass `D:\\transaction.list` as a filename

Comment: man this is wierd....  if i used the name of the text file with the spaces like  'infile.open("D:\New Text Document.txt",ios::in);' it worked but it doesnt work for the list with one \...

Comment: but for some reason i need to use two `\\` for the list..  its working fine now..  thanks...

Comment: @Pundit: A safer approach is to use '/' (forward slash) in filenames.  Both Windows and Linux platforms accept '/' a directory separators.